# Error instead of password prompt when admin privileges needed

Tags: permissions, 18.04, gui

I recently noticed some problems in my system: 
1. error "Unable to install ...: you do not have permission to install software" when I try to install anything from "Ubuntu software"
2. Nothing happens, when I press "Unlock" in user settings.

I'm pretty sure, both issues are connected. None of these are very significant for me (apt and useradd work properly).

Installing software through gui worked before, so I'm pretty sure, it is either an update or some package, I've installed, that causes the problem.

EDIT: 
I've found this output in journalctl in situations described above:

```
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN kernel: polkitd[6183]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f91635cbfa6 sp 00007ffdccb6c790 error 4 in libpolkit-backend-1.so.0.0.0[7f91635bc000+18000]
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN systemd[1]: polkit.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN systemd[1]: polkit.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1163]: PolicyKit daemon disconnected from the bus.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1163]: We are no longer a registered authentication agent.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN dbus-daemon[1044]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' unit='polkit.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=1048 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN gnome-control-c[2116]: Error acquiring permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1740]: PolicyKit daemon disconnected from the bus.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1740]: We are no longer a registered authentication agent.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN polkitd[6411]: started daemon version 0.105 using authority implementation `local' version `0.105'
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN dbus-daemon[1044]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1163]: PolicyKit daemon reconnected to bus.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1163]: Attempting to re-register as an authentication agent.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1740]: PolicyKit daemon reconnected to bus.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1740]: Attempting to re-register as an authentication agent.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN polkitd(authority=local)[6411]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c1 (system bus name :1.28 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1163]: We are now a registered authentication agent.
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN polkitd(authority=local)[6411]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.76 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
maj 24 23:33:21 tfrankowski-UX32LN org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1740]: We are now a registered authentication agent.
```

Answer (score 13):

The problem seem to be related to this file

> /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/02-allow-colord.conf

It stems from a [manual xRDP installation](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11336) (See comment section) or x2go or other remote desktop applications.

The [solution](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12043) comes from the same site:

Delete 02-allow-colord.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/02-allow-colord.conf
```

Create 45-allow-colord.pkla:

```
sudo vi /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/45-allow-colord.pkla
```

with content:

```
[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

then

```
sudo systemctl restart polkit.service
```