# Lost permissions to install software on ubuntu 1804

Tags: permissions, software-center

Relatively new to ubuntu...after installation i was able to install software with software center.  Now, however, i get the message that I don't have permission to install software.  There are no details and it is not prompting me for credentials or anything.

In between install ubuntu with software install privileges and now I have been setting up the system with zabbix, nginx, php, mysql, eclipse, etc....with no problems.

I also do not have privileges in software & updates etc.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is the output of sudo apt update:

```
jparker@jparker-desktop:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Ign:3 dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable InRelease    
Hit:4 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:5 ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Ign:6 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:7 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:8 dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb stable Release
Hit:9 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
18 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
jparker@jparker-desktop:~$
```

Here is the output of `echo $UID`

```
jparker@jparker-desktop:~$ echo $UID
1000
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo apt update` command.

Comment: Also please add output of `echo $UID`

Comment: note: i had to remove the http:// at the beginning of each package in case you're thinking that looks weird.  reputation points or something.....

Comment: Instead of removing `http` you can select the text and press `{}` format soft button.

Comment: All looks OK in terminal. You have permissions to update and upgrade. Regarding the GUI you seem to break something there yourself.

Comment: i'm not sure how i would have broken something as most of everything i installed/setup was through command line - wasn't even using the GUI for that.  That's what's so confusing.  I looked into polkit etc - that doesn't seem to affect this at all.  Not sure what to look at.

Comment: You can break everything using the command line. Now you can upgrade packages using `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Any idea how I would go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution here: [Error instead of password prompt when admin privileges needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039958/error-instead-of-password-prompt-when-admin-privileges-needed).

It had something to do with my installation of x2go....