# The "Unlock" button has no effect in the "Time and Date Settings" dialog

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, policykit

I am trying to change the timezone via UI.

In order to do that I run `time-admin` from a command line as a regular user.
(It is also possible to open the same dialog by right-clicking on the <kbd>Clock</kbd> component on the panel, choosing the <kbd>Properties</kbd> menu item and then clicking on the <kbd>Time and Date Settings...</kbd> button.)

The following message appears in the console output:

```
Gtk-Message: 15:58:40.008: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

and the dialog window opens:

[image: Time and Date Settings]

When I hover over the <kbd>Unlock</kbd> button, the tooltip appears: "Dialog is locked. Click to make changes".

If I click on the <kbd>Unlock</kbd> button then nothing happens on the screen, but an additional line appears in the console output:

```
** (time-admin:8856): WARNING **: 16:10:03.520: Error acquiring permission: Failed to acquire permission for action-id org.freedesktop.systemtoolsbackends.set
```

What does this message indicate and how to resolve this problem?

There is [an exactly same question at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-tools/+bug/1764379) and [a similar question at Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039958/error-instead-of-password-prompt-when-admin-privileges-needed), but both of them are unanswered.

The strange thing is that when I tried to create a new user and logged in to the system as that new user, the "Authenticate" window poped up for that user once I clicked the <kbd>Unlock</kbd> button.

Comment: It sounds like for some reason you do not the the rights to change the lock status. Did you make a new user other then the one you created during the install and you are logged in as that user and trying to open the lock? If so you need to be logged in as the user you made during the install.

Comment: @David, no, this is the same user that was created during the installation and this is the only user of the system. Moreover, if I try to add a new user via UI (`users-admin`), the "Add" button has no effect for me as well and there is nothing in the console output.

Comment: OK then I think that for what ever reason you have a corrupted system. I suggest download a new copy of the ISO. Make a new live media and reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. It is not a solution but a workaround with commandline:

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

to see the timezones and

```
timedatectl set-timezone "your/zone"
```

to set one.